# Can a CTE be called in another CTE, like can CTE2 use CTE1 results?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, oracle12c

Example is
 Suppose:

```
 with CTE1 as (select col1 from t1) select * from CTE1;
    with CTE2 as (select col2 from t2 where col2=col1)
    select * from CTE2;
```

Is this possible.
I have tried few codes, but none is of use.
 Please help me.

Comment: Your example does not feature calling a CTE in another CTE, indeed. And also, you have two separate `select` clauses which brings two independent data sets

Answer (score 5):

A CTE only exists within the query that defines it. Your second query does not know that the CTE from the first query ever existed.

You can refer to one CTE from another, as long as they're both part of the same query (and are defined in the right order), so you could do something like:

```
with CTE1 as (select t1.col1 from t1),
     CTE2 as (select t2.col2 from CTE1 join t2 on t2.col2=CTE1.col1)
select * from CTE2;
```

The two CTE definitions are separated by a comma (as [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)), and the order matters. In that rather contrived example, you can refer to CTE1 from CTE2; but you cannot refer to CTE2 from CTE1 because it hasn't been defined yet, as far as the parser is concerned.

The main query can refer to either or both CTEs, even if one already references the other. And you can chain more than two CTEs together in the same way.